# Various images sizes using fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox

on the fancybos site it says that to use multiple image sizes one need to:

```
<a href="medium.jpg" data-fancybox="images" data-srcset="large.jpg 1600w, medium.jpg 1200w, small.jpg 640w">
    <img src="thumbnail.jpg" />
</a>
```

Do 1600w, 1200w & 640w signify the device screen width in px?

Comment: Easy enough to test with the developer tools responsive design option.

Answer (score 0):

The script takes value of `data-srcset` and sets `srcset` attribute for the image, the rest is up to the browser, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#attr-srcset